# How to detect if a button is clicked or not

Tags: php

I have a simple php coding problem here. I have a button id 'register' for user to click. But the code below does not run it once the button is clicked.

```
<?php
try {

 if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    require_once('library.php');

    $user_id = $identity->user_id; 
    $status_type = 'M';
    $data = array('status' => $status_type);

    $dbWrite->update('user', $data, "user_id = $user_id");

    header('Location: main.php');
    exit;
 }

} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: Is the button's `name` attribute also set to 'register'? It might help if you included the HTML form, too.

Comment: What form method you are using GET or POST

Comment: Can you show us the HTML for your button?

Comment: <p><input name="register" type="submit" id="register" value="Register" /></p>

Comment: do a `var_dump($_POST);` to see if you detect some anomalies.

Comment: the id parameter is not passed, the name parameter is. Are you setting it? Second, it wont be passed if the users presses enter instead of clicking on the button

Comment: Can you show us the form tag as well?

Comment: @user2359714 - you _do_ have that HTML wrapped in `<form>` tags, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Name attribute of your button must be missed. Define button in HTML like below

```
<input type="submit" name="register" value="register" />
```

Answer (score 0):

write `print_r($_POST);` and see what is missing

maybe a syntax of `form`